# mysql query not giving accurate result

Tags: mysql, sql

I am working on a query whose purpose is to get the records of all the students   whose financialyear_id!=4 and don't dispaly records even if he/she has     finacialyear_id other then 4  exist.
I have written a query but it gives me the record of that student whose     finacialyear_id!=4 but I want to achieve that no records will be shown if    financialyear_id=4 exist for any student.

```
SELECT a.id aid
     , s.id sid
     , s.name
     , s.father_name
     , s.cnic
     , f.financialyear_id 
  FROM student s 
  JOIN academic_info a 
    ON a.s_id = s.id
  LEFT 
  JOIN fee_issued f 
    ON a.id = f.academic_info_id
 WHERE f.financialyear_id != 4 
   AND a.is_data_locked = 0 
   AND a.university_id = 60;
```

Foreign Key: s_id in both tables academic_info and fee_issued,academic_info_id in fee_issued table.

Comment: why all of you down voting if u don't want to help then please don't see this.

Comment: Nice! Man really great that you're working! But i'll go again because you got no question to answer

Comment: then kindly tell what I am doing wrong guide me instead of down voting

Comment: Please go through this before Asking a Question on SO http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: As an aside, note that LEFT JOIN x WHERE x = 'a' is the same as INNER JOIN x...

Comment: It would be good for those downvoting to explain the reason

Comment: I would recommend you to read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/advice?). Then come back and ask your question again. Because at the moment its really hard to understand what you really mean

Comment: The downvotes are fun, but a close vote may actually be more meaningful. zeeshan, if you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper CREATE and INSERT statements (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: There can be many academic_info per student and many fee_issued per academic_info. So: You want to select all these combinations, but only for students that have no financialyear 4 record. Is this correct?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner yes even if they have finacialyear 1,2,3 I don't want to show that student.
you got my point.

Answer (score 0):

You used a keyword in your request: "but I want to achieve that no records will be shown if financialyear_id=4 **exist** for any student." So use `EXISTS` (or `IN` which does about the same) to check for existence.

As you are using MySQL you must write the select condition for `academic_info` twice. Other DBMS handle this more elegantly.

```
select a.id as aid, s.id as sid, s.name, s.father_name, s.cnic, f.financialyear_id
from student s
join academic_info a on a.s_id = s.id and a.is_data_locked = 0 and a.university_id = 60
left join fee_issued f on f.academic_info_id = a.id
where s.id not in
(
  select ai.s_id
  from academic_info ai
  join fee_issued fi on fi.academic_info_id = ai.id and fi.financialyear_id != 4
  where ai.is_data_locked = 0 and ai.university_id = 60
);
```

Above query also gets you students that have no fee_issued at all. If you want these removed, change the left join to an inner join.

EDIT: Here is the same with NOT EXISTS.

```
select a.id as aid, s.id as sid, s.name, s.father_name, s.cnic, f.financialyear_id
from student s
join academic_info a on a.s_id = s.id and a.is_data_locked = 0 and a.university_id = 60
left join fee_issued f on f.academic_info_id = a.id
where not exists
(
  select *
  from academic_info ai
  join fee_issued fi on fi.academic_info_id = ai.id and fi.financialyear_id != 4
  where ai.is_data_locked = 0 and ai.university_id = 60
  and ai.s_id = s.id
);
```

Comment: I don't want to use subquery... it is slow as compare to join anyway thanks for your answer

Comment: I doubt that. That would mean that MySQL is a very weak DBMS that is not able to handle simple IN/EXISTS expressions properly. Using anti joins instead, which seems to be what you have in mind here would make the query less readable by far and I wouldn't recommend going this route. If this query is too slow for you then there is probably something wrong with your database setup. This is not at all a complicated query and should be no problem for the DBMS hence.

Comment: but as compared to joins with subquery you also know this that joins are faster then subquery and I have large number of records so what you suggest in that case?

Comment: I simply think you are making up a Problem here that doesn't exist. Yes, joins are often faster, especially when a DBMS is rather new and ist programmers have not yet cared too much about other things than the very basic ones. This is not the case with MySQL, however, I daresay, as MySQL is not new. And a good DBMS will find the best execution plan for a query anyhow. So if MySQL finds out that the IN clause is best approached by joining tables somehow, then it will do so internally.

Comment: I know that once you deal with billions of records and very large and complex queries, you may get to a point when you need to trick the DBMS into finding the right way. But are you really dealing with that many records? And even if that were so, this query simply isn't complex or even large at all. Write your queries as simple as possible. Only when you really run into performance issues, think of alternatives.

Comment: yes your points are valid and this query gives me the record as required but yes I have a performance issues for above query as i run for specific university but for generic case it seems to be faster but it is slow 
can you tell Can I achieve that result with join or not as I am trying,debugging how to get the result in join but I am not getting successfull

Comment: I am pretty sure you won't get this faster with joins. You would probably have to outer-join an aggregate and then dismiss this (anti join) which is much more work for the DBMS then the simple NOT IN clause. Indexes may help. There should be indexes on the IDs used of course, but you may also want to consider covering indexes, e.g. an index on academic_info(s_id, university_id, is_data_locked).

Comment: I've added a query with NOT EXISTS. This should result in the same execution plan actually, but MySQL was known once for having problems with IN clauses, so maybe this helps. But as mentioned: the main thing when optimizing access is having appropriate indexes.

Comment: yes indexes are already covered...anyways thanks for the help.appreciated